# writing text file from MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io, text-files

I am trying to export a double array from MATLAB into a txt file. I can do this easily but the data is not structured how i need it. I need the data to be structured in the following way in the txt file;

```
-0.0195
-0.0217
-0.0260
-0.0274
-0.0258
-0.0246
-0.0244
-0.0233
-0.0209
-0.0221
```

Does anyone know how this would be done using `dlmwrite`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
A=[-0.0195; -0.0217; -0.0260; -0.0274; -0.0258; -0.0246; -0.0244; -0.0233; -0.020;-0.0221];
dlmwrite('example.txt', A, 'newline', 'pc')
```

The last two argument determines the new line character used (CR or CR+LF), depending on the platform. Use `'pc'` for the Windows version, and `'unix'` for all others.

For full cross-platformness, you can use the `isunix` function, and have something like the following preceding your code:

```
if isunix==true
   platform='unix'
else
   platform='pc'
end
```

and then use the `platform` variable as the last argument in `dlmwrite`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried that and it still does not structure the data how i need it, in a single column. There are a huge amount of lines in the array to write to txt file.

Comment: @MikeAllen: You have to make sure your array is a column vector. If not, adjust as necessary. Make a simple example and show precisely what input do you use, and what output do you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a row-vector called `A` this will write it into a column in `afile.txt`:

```
dlmwrite('afile.txt',A,'\n')
```